# Drop and add constraints in one stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I would like to drop a primary key and then add a primary key to the same column in 1 stored procedure.

I have the drop constraints within `Begin Transaction' and`Commit Transaction`then try to add the constraints within another set of`Begin Transaction`and`Commit Transaction`.

I am getting the error that a primary key already exists for this column when it was dropped in the first set of transactions.

This is the code:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Lens] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Lens_Style];
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Lens] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Lens_Type];
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Coating] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_Coatings];
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CoatingCost] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_CoatingCost];

COMMIT TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Coating] 
      ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Coating] 
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CoatingId] ASC)
                  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

If the first set of constraints are dropped and committed, shouldn't I be able to add a primary key on the column that previously had a primary key?

**UPDATE**
I think I know the problem.  It is because there is a Foreign Key associated with the primary key that I am trying to drop.

I will need to drop all of the foreign keys associated with all of the primary keys that I am trying to drop.  Then add the primary keys back. Then add the foreign keys back.

Comment: try to `DISABLE` and `ENABLE` instead of `DROP` and `ADD`

Comment: I have to drop the constraint because it need to be renamed or dropped permanently.

Comment: This isn't going to work quite like that. To do this in a single procedure will require you to move the code to dynamic sql. This is because the compiler will raise an exception because the table already has a primary key. It does not run through your logic to determine the primary key has already been dropped. I would question why you need a stored procedure for this in the first place. Do you really drop and recreate primary keys so frequently you need a procedure for it?

Comment: this stored procedure is keeping our many databases in sync.  So it is needed.  I thought by committing the drop transactions first  will remove the constraints then adding the constraints would work.  The compiler does not have to read the logic.  Running the first set of instructions to drop the constraint would allow adding it back.

Comment: what does `commit transaction` do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the problem is not with the same index name existing in the database in the moment when your code tries to create one? The name of an index must be unique in the entire database scope not only in a single table scope.
You might want to diagnose it by putting a below query before, between and after your transaction operations:

```
   SELECT
   so.name AS tableName
   , si.name AS indexName
   , si.type_desc AS indexType
   , si.is_primary_key AS isPK
   FROM
   sys.indexes AS si
   JOIN sys.objects AS so ON si.object_id = so.object_id
   WHERE
   si.name IS NOT NULL /*otherwise it will select all tables without explicit index*/
   AND
   so.type = 'U'/*otherwise it unnecessarily will select indexes of system tables*/
```

Comment: No.  The problem seems to be is that at the beginning of the stored procedure I drop the primary key named **PK_Coatings** for table **Coating** then Commit the Transaction.  Then try to add the primary key constraint **PK_dbo.Coating** for table **Coating** and it fails because it reports that there is a primary key for the table **Coating**.  But I dropped it and committed it.  So why is it still there?